# Increase wireframe thickness with react-three-fiber

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-three-fiber

I am trying to increase the thickness of a sphere wireframe.
It works fine using three.js but I am not sure how to translate this to react-three-fiber

Three.js

```
      var geometry = new WireframeGeometry2(geo);
      const matLine = new LineMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff,
        linewidth: 2,
      });
      matLine.resolution.set(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      const mesh = new Wireframe(geometry, matLine);
    scene.add(mesh);
```

React-three-fiber

```
const Globe = () => {
  return (
    <mesh>
      <sphereBufferGeometry args={[2, 9, 9]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial wireframe wireframeLinewidth={0.5} />
    </mesh>
  );
};
```

Where `wireframeLinewidth` doesn't work, as explained in the [dcumentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.wireframeLinewidth)

Any Ideas?

Comment: What is your code in `react-three-fiber`?

Comment: Not much at the moment, as I just started, I will add it to the question

Comment: For anyone coming here, referenced documentation also says: "Due to limitations of the OpenGL Core Profile with the WebGL renderer on most platforms linewidth will always be 1 regardless of the set value."

Comment: As Pete Kayson said, I know in threejs it will always draw it as 1 thick, but you can use libraries replace the lines with a mesh: https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine

Answer (score 0):

```
import { LineMaterial } from 'three/examples/jsm/lines/LineMaterial';
import { Wireframe } from 'three/examples/jsm/lines/Wireframe';
import { WireframeGeometry2 } from 'three/examples/jsm/lines/WireframeGeometry2';
import { useRef, useMemo } from 'react';
import { useFrame } from 'react-three-fiber';

function MyComponent({ geo }) {
  const meshRef = useRef();

  const geometry = useMemo(() => new WireframeGeometry2(geo), [geo]);
  const matLine = useMemo(
    () =>
      new LineMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff,
        linewidth: 2,
      }),
    []
  );
  matLine.resolution.set(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  const mesh = useMemo(() => new Wireframe(geometry, matLine), [geometry, matLine]);

  useFrame(() => {
    meshRef.current.rotation.x += 0.01;
    meshRef.current.rotation.y += 0.01;
  });

  return (
    <mesh ref={meshRef}>
      <primitive object={mesh} />
    </mesh>
  );
}
```